# Create new Image view at runtime based on users touch and Animate ImageView to another ImageVIew

Tags: android, animation

Hi I have this app with a gridlist of images, my idea is when the user clicks on one of the images a floating images will show on that same location and animate to the main image holders position,. I tried something like this, i add a view at runtime and set it to gone for performance, my problem is copying the same img view that was click in my gridview, and set the floating location base on getX and getY on onTouchLister, but the floating image is not showing where the user touch and the images lags, here is my code

```
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener,
        OnPageChangeListener, UpdateAvatarProgressListener, OnTouchListener {

      ViewGroup mParentView;

      float getX;
      float getY;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_edit);

        mParentView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.fragment_edit_id);
        img = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);     
        img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mParentView.addView(img);
        GridView gridView= (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.img_gridview);
          gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                 img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_holder);
                 img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

      int[] img_coordinates = new int[2];
      mainImageHolder.getLocationOnScreen(img_coordinates);
      float x = (float) (img_coordinates[0] + mainImageHolder.getWidth() / 2.0);
      float y = (float) (img_coordinates[1] + mainImageHolder.getHeight() / 2.0);
      TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(getX, getY, x, y);
      anim.setDuration(800);

      anim.setAnimationListener(new TranslateAnimation.AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) { 
          img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
      });

      img.startAnimation(anim);
            }
        }
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getX = event.getX();
        getY = event.getY();
        return false;
      }
    }
```

I need something like this [link](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/09/19/crossing-boundaries-with-the-new-android-viewoverlay/) but i don't want to use ViewOverlay because it supports only api 18, i was wondering about the windowmanager but i read that you can't animate in windowmanager using custom. also im using a fragment,

<strike>I have this imageviews one is the main image view and some small image view.</strike>

```
mainimage

imageview1
imageview2
imageview3
imageview4
imageview5
```

Im new to animations and i want to try something

now when i click the imageview1
i want to animate a move effect from imageview1 to mainimage
then set the value of mainimage to imageview1
same if other images has been clicked.

here is my code

```
   griView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
          ImageLibrary imgLib = adapter.get(position);  


              mainImage = imgLib;


        }
      });
```

i tried something like this

```
 mImagesGridView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          getX = event.getX();
          getY = event.getY();
          return false;
        }
      });

      mImagesGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { 

          TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(getX,  getY, mGroupImageImageView.getX(),
              mGroupImageImageView.getY());
          anim.setDuration(600);

          anim.setAnimationListener(new TranslateAnimation.AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
              // set image in mainImage view


              final float growTo = 0.7f;
              final long duration = 200;

              ScaleAnimation grow = new ScaleAnimation(1, growTo, 1, growTo,
                  Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
              grow.setDuration(duration / 2);
              ScaleAnimation shrink = new ScaleAnimation(growTo, 1, growTo, 1,
                  Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
              shrink.setDuration(duration / 2);
              shrink.setStartOffset(duration / 2);
              AnimationSet growAndShrink = new AnimationSet(true);
              growAndShrink.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
              growAndShrink.addAnimation(grow);
              growAndShrink.addAnimation(shrink);
              mGroupImageImageView.startAnimation(growAndShrink); 
            }
          });

          view.findViewById(R.id.Image_imageview).startAnimation(anim);

        }
      });
```

Comment: when you say "move effect from imageview1 to mainimage" will imageview1 goes to the top of mainimage? or under?

Comment: top of mainimage, then set the value of mainimage, also the imageview1 will remain on its main position after setting the value of mainimage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, amountToMoveRight, amountToMoveDown);
anim.setDuration(1000);

anim.setAnimationListener(new TranslateAnimation.AnimationListener() {

@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) 
{
   // set image in mainImage view 
}
});

view.startAnimation(anim);
```

Comment: it doesn't move where is the position of mainimage,

Comment: you have find x, y of the main image view and pass it to TranslateAnimation like this TranslateAnimation(x_current, y_curreny, x_mainview, y_mainview);

Comment: and you can find the location of view like this view.getLocationOnScreen()

Comment: I see. I thought TranslateAnimation is (x_current, x_mainview,  y_curreny , y_mainview).

Comment: i have updated my question with the following code i use but the images is not moving to mainimage

Comment: may be try with some constant value, if it still not work try to replace gridview with relative view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55412/discussion-between-asheesh-and-user3487657).

Answer (score 0):

I guess this sample from Google fits your requirement

http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html

Get the source code and make some modifications.